# Ansible modules for automate switch Huawei S5700 configuration

Tags: huawei

Consulting Ansible webpage, I found modules for Huawei CloudEngine series (ce_command, ce_config, etc). But theses modules don't work for others families like switches S5700.

So, what Ansible modules should I use to automate Huawei S5700 configuration process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no device-specific modules for that device, but that device can be configured from the command line, so you can use the Ansible CLI modules:

> ### [Network modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/list_of_network_modules.html#network-modules)
>
> ### [Cli](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/list_of_network_modules.html#cli)
>
> - [cli_command – Run a cli command on cli-based network devices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/cli_command_module.html#cli-command-module)
> - [cli_config – Push text based configuration to network devices over    network_cli](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/cli_config_module.html#cli-config-module)

Comment: Ansible returns "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module" when using these modules. So I had to set ansible_connection variable to 'network_cli'.

Once set , Ansible returns a second message: "Unable to automatically determine host network os. Please manually configure ansible_network_os value for this host". So I used 'ce' value intuitively and... It works! (Thank you @Ron).

But, searching [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_index.html) I didn't find de CE operating system. Is CloudEngine OS going to be discontinued?

Comment: the links seem expired. Is it possible to manage huawei switch with ansible?

Comment: In the search box that comes up when you go to the link, type `cli`.